# How can I get the sum of the volumes?

Tags: java

I'm just now starting my Computer Science degree and am still very new to this, what I've done is multiplied radius' and depth to get the volume. However, I'm stuck on how to then add them all together, the code is as follows (sorry for the poor explanation).

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Pipe p1=new Pipe(20,40,60);
    p1.print();
    Pipe p2=new Pipe(30,98,20);
    p2.print();
    Pipe p3=new Pipe(40,55,100);
    p3.print();
    //Pipe p;
    //p=new Pipe();
    //p.innerRadius=20;
    //p.outerRadius=40;
    //p.depth=60;
    //p.print();
}
}

class Pipe
{
  double innerRadius;
  double outerRadius;
  double depth;

  public Pipe(int i, int o, int d)
  {
      this.innerRadius=i;
      this.outerRadius=o;
      this.depth=d;
  }

  public void print()
  {
      System.out.println(this.innerRadius);
      System.out.println(this.outerRadius);
      System.out.println(this.depth);
      System.out.println(volume());
  }

  public double volume()
  {
      double pi=3.1415;
      return pi*this.innerRadius*this.outerRadius*this.depth;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is *the sum of the results*? are you talking about `volume()` method? you already return value from there.

Comment: Sorry! I should have been more clear, I want to add all of the volumes together, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: In the `print()` function, instead of printing the volume, return it. In the `main()` function, assign a variable and keep adding the individual pipe volumes that you return. Alternately you may use a loop and auto add the returned values during the iteration of the loop. This way is better imo. 
Edit: It is as Guy just said in the answers. But use a loop or else you will have to keep adding the same statement over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add the volumes by adding the following line in the main method:

```
double total_volume = p1.volume() + p2.volume() + p3.volume();
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! SO many cogs just clicked when looking at this haha!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double totalVolume = 0;
        Pipe p1 = new Pipe(20,40,60);
        p1.print();
        Pipe p2 = new Pipe(30,98,20);
        p2.print();
        Pipe p3 = new Pipe(40,55,100);
        p3.print();
        totalVolume = p1.volume() + p2.volume() + p3.volume();
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + totalVolume);
    }
}
```

**Pipe Class:**

```
public class Pipe {
      double innerRadius;
      double outerRadius;
      double depth;

      public Pipe(int i, int o, int d)
      {
          this.innerRadius=i;
          this.outerRadius=o;
          this.depth=d;
      }

      public void print()
      {
          System.out.println(this.innerRadius);
          System.out.println(this.outerRadius);
          System.out.println(this.depth);
          System.out.println(volume());
      }

      public double volume()
      {
          double pi = 3.1415;
          return (pi*this.innerRadius*this.outerRadius*this.depth);
      }

}
```

**Modifications:**

1. You forgot to call `volume()` method in order to calculate volume.
2. Secondly I added a double `totalVolume` variable which is responsible for total of all volumes.
3. I have separated both the classes. You must follow same approach for better understanding and later modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the return results to a variable

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double sum = 0;
    Pipe p1 = new Pipe(20,40,60);
    p1.print();
    sum += p1.volume();
    Pipe p2 = new Pipe(30,98,20);
    p2.print();
    sum += p2.volume();
    Pipe p3 = new Pipe(40,55,100);
    p3.print();
    sum += p3.volume();
}
```